# Searching for Modules, Macros

Tags: reaktor

I do a decent amount of coding, and am used to being able to recursively search for text strings in a codebase.

I was recently looking to see how some of the Reaktor factory ensembles implement glide/glissando/portamento.

I found such in the following ensembles:

- 2-Osc
- Carbon
- Oki-Computer
- FM4 (and dual)

And am sure there are others.

In Oki-Computer, it took a lot of digging, deleting large parts of the ensemble to track down, for instance, the source of the "Glide" knob, which is in `Gate Pitch` - > `Mono` -> `Glide`.

I imagine that this will be more intuitive as I become more familiar with Reaktor and modular synthesis and general.

Is there an approach to searching through modules, ensembles, libraries for specific text strings and/or modules, cells?